# How/Where to optimise SSIS Package that causes sql queries to take extremely long to execute?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I currently have a parent SSIS package that executes 4 child packages. Each child package transfers a table between source SQL server to a destination SQL server and executes the following SQL queries in the destination SQL server:

1. Creation of Table
2. Renaming of Tables
3. Dropping of Table

I frequently encounter the following error "timeout expired.the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation" and the SQL server becomes extremely slow and unresponsive in SSMS. However, this does not happen much if I execute only 2 child packages in parallel. How can I prevent this while executing more tasks in parallel? Where should I be looking to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Does the parent package execute the childs simultaneously or one after another?

I think in a case where the childs are executed simultaneously, you can have issues with resource lock since you perform DDL queries.

Comment: The parent package executes the child packages simultaneously which perform ddl queries on the same database.  Hence, what you said maybe the reason. Do you have any suggestions on how I could execute child packages in parallel but yet execute the queries such that they do not affect one another?